# Use a change of variables to transform the above integral to an integral over the cube $ \ \{0<u<1, \ 0<v<1, \ 0<w<1 \} \ $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the tripple integral $ \ \large \int_{2}^{3} \int_{4}^{8} \int_0^{10} \sin (xy-z) dxdydz \ $

Use a change of variables to transform the above integral to an integral over the cube  $ \ \{0<u<1, \ 0<v<1, \ 0<w<1 \} \ $

**Answer:**

I am having the problem to find the required transformation from the given domain to the unit cube.

The given domain is

$ \ 0 \leq x \leq 10, \\ 4 \leq y \leq 8 , \\ 2 \leq z \leq 3 \ $

We have to find a transformation $ \ u=\phi(x,y,z) , \ v=\psi(x,y,z), \ w=\eta(x,y,z) \ $ that maps the given domain into the unit cube $ \ \{0<u<1, 0<v<1 , 0<w<1 \} \ $

Let us consider the transformation $ u=\frac{1}{10}x(x-9) , \ v=\frac{1}{4} y-1 , \ w=z-2 \ $

**Will this transformation work ?**

But I think this will make complicated when subsituted in the integral.

Any other easy transformation keeping in mind the integrand $ \ \sin (xy-z) \ $ will be helpful

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the transformation
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x}{10}\\\frac{y-4}{4}\\z-2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Next we have to find the Jacombian ? Is not it ?

Comment: yes of the above transformation

Comment: @yourmath certainly, good luck (I don't think this actually helps you compute the integral)

Comment: Do you have any doubt in the process to compute the integral ?

Comment: @yourmath i would try and change coordinates to get rid of the $xy-z=u$ and leave the other's fixed. The bounds are a little annoying, but it should be doable.